# efficient way to compare multiple int values to 0

Tags: java, boolean

I'm trying to compare three lengths to 0 and was wondering if there was a more efficient/cleaner way than repeating "!= 0".

```java
public static boolean isTriangle(int lengthA, int lengthB, int lengthC) {
    if (lengthA != 0 && lengthB != 0 && lengthC != 0) { //is there a shorter/cleaner way to write this?
        //do a thing
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not what you're asking, but to be a triangle, it's not enough for the three lengths to just be non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking three things; you're asking for code that is

1. shorter
2. more efficient
3. cleaner

I have an alternative for you:

```
if ((lengthA & lengthB & lengthC) != 0)
```

It's correct - it does the same as your old code (it uses bitwise-and)

1. it is **shorter**.
2. it's potentially *more efficient* but only a good microbenchmark can confirm. Even if it is, that shouldn't guide you. Because of point 3, you should only consider it if it shows up as a bottleneck in your app using a performance analyzer tool, which is very, very unlikely.
3. however it's **not *cleaner***. And with that I mean that it will make your code harder to read and understand, and anyone maintaining your code will now have to think about bit manipulation.

Most likely the same will go for any proposed alternative.

What you were doing in your original code is good enough; it's what people understand, and it's most likely the cleanest code you can write for the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `IntStream` and `allMatch`

```
if(IntStream.of(lengthA,lengthB,lengthC).allMatch(i->i!=0)) {
     // do a thing
  }
```

or by using `noneMatch` also

```
IntStream.of(lengthA,lengthB,lengthC).noneMatch(i->i==0)
```

The other way around you do this is by having a util method

```
public static boolean isNotZero(int val) {
       return val!=0;
     }
```

Now simplify the `if` condition

```
if (isNotZero(lengthA) && isNotZero(lengthB) && isNotZero(lengthC)) {
```

Comment: This is correct but it’s not more efficient than three equality tests.

Comment: i don't know the implemented of `allMatch` and `noneMatch`, but may i know why? @VGR

Comment: Well, the three equality tests will literally become three assembly instructions (or maybe six), once they are JIT-compiled.  IntStream.of will, at the very least, need to create two objects, an IntStream instance and an int array for the vararg arguments, then garbage collect them when the if-test completes.

Comment: Yes, it's not going to be more efficient.  Most people would also find it less readable.  I'm not going to count the characters to judge whether it's shorter.  I think OP's original code is a pretty good way of testing this condition.

Comment: i just updated the another approach by using util method VGR, @DawoodibnKareem

Answer (score 1):

**Best answer (IMHO):**  *"Don't even try to second-guess the optimizing compiler."*  Just specify the source-code in the way that most accurately specifies *(to your fellow humans, nothing more ...)* what you want the computer to do.  Don't presume that the actual sequence of machine instructions that is actually given to the hardware actually corresponds to this.  *"It's magic.  Really."*

Answer (score 0):

For Java language, your code is good. There's no better way to do this in Java.